# window taskbar notification like skype

Tags: java, taskbar

I am interested to implement a window taskbar notification function similar to what skype has, whereby there is a small circle is pinned on the bottom right side of the taskbar with the number when there is a incoming message.

[image]

But however I don't know what to search for. Please help.

Comment: I don't think it's unclear at all. see that notification yellow circle and (1). how to set the icon to that in windows.

the tray is different btw.

I happen to be googling around for solution to this that would work from a background window and this page is high up in the rankings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWT provides an API for system tray (note that not all platforms are supported): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

If you want to change the image (e.g. showing the number of incoming messages), then you can provide a new image using: [TrayIcon.setImage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#setImage-java.awt.Image-)